# hint message on dropdown not showing in flutter

Tags: flutter

Please help, the hint message in the dropdown on my flutter doesn't appear
here is my code:

in component :

```
import 'package:dropdown_button2/custom_dropdown_button2.dart';
import 'package:dropdown_button2/dropdown_button2.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ButtonItems<T> extends StatelessWidget {
double width;
double height;
void Function(T?)? onChanged;
bool isExpended;
Color bgColor;
double dropdownWidth;
double radius;
double widthContainerBottom;
double heightContainerBottom;
double widthContainerText;
double heightContainerText;
Color colorBorder;
Color bgColorText;
String? errMessage;
String textDate;
bool isDate;
Widget? hint;
DropdownMenuItem<T> Function(dynamic) createChild;
T value;
List<dynamic> items;

ButtonItems(
  {Key? key,
  this.width = 300.0,
  this.dropdownWidth = 300.0,
  this.height = 50.0,
  required this.value,
  this.isExpended = true,
  this.onChanged,
  this.hint,
  this.widthContainerBottom = 100,
  this.heightContainerBottom = 40,
  this.widthContainerText = 45,
  this.heightContainerText = 17,
  this.bgColorText = Colors.white,
  required this.createChild,
  required this.items,
  this.textDate = "date",
  this.isDate = true,
  this.errMessage,
  this.bgColor = Colors.transparent,
  this.radius = 10.0,
  this.colorBorder = Colors.white})
  : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Container(
  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
  margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10),
  width: width,
  height: height,
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(radius),
    color: bgColor,
  ),
  child: DropdownButton2<T>(  
    dropdownWidth: dropdownWidth,
    dropdownDecoration: BoxDecoration(
      color: Colors.white,
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
        bottomLeft: Radius.circular(15),
        bottomRight: Radius.circular(15),
      ),
    ),
    offset: Offset(-10, 8),
    dropdownElevation: 0,
    dropdownMaxHeight: 200,
    dropdownFullScreen: true,
    scrollbarAlwaysShow: true,
    icon: Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_down),
    iconSize: 25,
    hint: hint,
    isExpanded: isExpended,
    value: value,
    items: [...items.map((e) => createChild(e))],
    onChanged: onChanged,
    underline: Container(),
  ),
);
}
}
```

when displaying on the page

```
                   ButtonItems<String>(
                        widthContainerBottom: device.width * 0.85,
                        width: device.width * 0.85,
                        height: 40,
                        dropdownWidth: device.width * 0.85,
                        bgColor: Colors.white,
                        value: valueGender,
                        hint: Row(
                          children: [
                            Icon(Icons.male),
                            SizedBox(width: 10),
                            Text("Choose your gender"),
                          ],
                        ),
                        onChanged: (data) {
                          setState(() {
                            valueGender = data!.toLowerCase();
                            print(data);
                          });
                        },
                        createChild: (data) {
                          var getMap = data as Map<String, String>;
                          return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                              value: getMap['name']!.toLowerCase(),
                              child: Container(
                                margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
                                child: Row(
                                  children: [
                                    Image.asset(
                                      getMap['image']!,
                                      width: 20,
                                    ),
                                    Container(
                                      margin:
                                          const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
                                      child: Text(
                                        getMap['name']!,
                                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ));
                   },
                  items: gender),
```

Please guide, how to display the hint message from the dropdown

Thank you for the help

Here's the current view[In this picture the dropdown is directly selected, no hint message appears](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7icFJ.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

according to documentation hint wont show up unless `value` is null and `onchanged` is non-null. in your case you have a value so your hint won't be displayed.
What I usually do to dropdown buttons like this is disable value and make the hint as my main placeholder. That's easier than trying to fight against value and hint.